# How can i pass strings from a file as keyboard input for a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I've got a script which is configuring a software.
When i run the script it asks for user input like the ports etc.

Is it possible to run the script and pass it strings from a file?

My file with inputs looks like:

```
8080
1100
password
password
y
```

I've tried to run this:

```
cat /installation/inputs | /etc/init.d/myprogram configure
```

EDIT:
After editing the password the command worked.
Maybe there was a wrong char in it which caused the error...

Comment: can you show us the output you're getting?

Comment: The output is an endless loop of the message "input3 cannot be null. Enter input3:" until i stop it with ^C.

Comment: I mean: copy/paste the real input of your program and the real values and [edit] your question for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax below will run your script and pass each line of text from /installation/inputs as a single line of arguments.

/etc/init.d/myprogram configure `echo $(cat /installation/inputs)`

results in:

/etc/init.d/myprogram configure 8080 1100 password password y

Your script simply needs to check if there are command line args, assign each arg $1 - $5 to each necessary field and then bypass the input prompts.